# Calling a parent from an instantiated child fails strict standards

Tags: oop, parent-child

I am trying to call a parent method from its child which has the same method name. Doing so results in a strict standards error. There's an easy solution of renaming the child method. However, is there a way to keep the names of the two methods identical without a standards warning? Thanks.

*Strict standards: Declaration of Child::getContentFromDb() should be compatible with Parent::getContentFromDb($id) in /foo/Child.class.php on line xxx*

Pseudo-code example:

```
class Parent {
    protected function getInfoFromDb($id) {
        return $infoFromDb;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public static $id = xx;
    public $info = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->info = $this->getInfoFromDb();
    }

    public function getInfoFromDb() {
        // the line below causes the problem
        return parent::getInfoFromDb(self::$id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method override should take the same parameter list as the one you are overriding.

e.g.

```
class ParentClass {

    protected function getInfoFromDb($id) {
        return "INFO FROM DB:" . $id;
    }
}

class Child extends ParentClass {
    public static $id = "xx";
    public $info = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->info = $this->getInfoFromDb();
    }

    /**
     * @param specific ID, or do not set for default action.
     * @return string
     */
    public function getInfoFromDb($id = false) {
        return parent::getInfoFromDb(self::$id);
    }
}
```